# Finding an appropriate continuous functions

Tags: calculus, continuity

> **Q**: Find examples of:
>
> 1) A continuous function $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ which is bounded but does not attain a maximum or minimum on $(0,1)$
>
> 2) A continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is bounded but does not attain a maximum or minimum on $\mathbb{R}$
>
> 3) A continuous function  $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ which is unbounded above and below

my take:

$1) y=x$ because inf of $f$ is $0$

$2) y=\arctan(x)$ this never touches $-1,1$

$3) y= \tan(x)$?

Do these 3 examples answers the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (2), $\tan^{-1}$ does touch $\pm 1$, but it does not touch $\pm \pi/2$.

$\tan$ does not work for (3). It is bounded on the closed interval $[0,1]$.
Try scaling it horizontally.

Comment: i mean pi/2 so 2 should work fine. but doesnt tan x continuous and unbounded?

Comment: i couldnt think of any for 3, could you give me a function

Comment: @Allie Yes $\tan^{-1}$ does work for (2), just for a different reasoning. As for (3), try $\tan (\pi x - \pi/2)$.